# node-pre-gyp: Permission denied in heroku push

Tags: heroku, npm, mean-stack, bcrypt

I'm pushing my MEAN stack app to heroku but an error is arising. 
[image]

I have tried to install node-pre-gyp but the error still there. I really dont know how to fix this.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nodejs Bcrypt + Heroku fail deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287669/nodejs-bcrypt-heroku-fail-deploy)

Comment: Also, consider removing `node_modules/` from your repository entirely. Let Heroku install your dependencies from your `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`.

Comment: my solution was to uninstall bcrypt, and install bcryptJS. it is weird but it worked. Thank you for your replies

Answer (score 6):

Remove **node_modules folder** in your root folder `rm -rf node_modules` beacuse heroku will **install all your dependencies**, I hope this will work

Answer (score 3):

**node-pre-gyp: Permission denied in heroku push**::
Just ran into this error just now, researching got me here. So i tried what [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354577/chris) advised.
Try deleting the **node_modules** from your repo, let Heroku install them itself, then the **node-pre-gyp** won't be an issue,
 oh, also remember to add the engine in your package.json file

```
//package.json
    "engines": {
        "node": "10.16.0"
      }
```

so that heroku doesn't use a default version, which might not be compatible to most of your installed packages.

NB: use node --version, in your cmd to know your node version.