# Heroku building failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord.js

I tried to deploy my discord bot on Heroku but all I got is a lot of errors on the build log and I have no idea about it.

My bot is working fine without any issues and I am pretty sure about it, and I can host my bot 100% without problems using my computer but I don't know where is the problem here

Here is my `build log`:

```
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.18.4...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.6
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
       Rebuilding any native modules
       
       > @discordjs/opus@0.3.2 install /tmp/build_4f5f37cb_/node_modules/@discordjs/opus
       > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
       
       sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! errno 126
       npm ERR! @discordjs/opus@0.3.2 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
       npm ERR! Exit status 126
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Failed at the @discordjs/opus@0.3.2 install script.
       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.KeDLW/_logs/2020-10-06T05_12_33_544Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - node_modules checked into source control
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#only-git-the-important-bits
       
       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56530659/node-pre-gyp-permission-denied-in-heroku-push

Answer (score 0):

If you still need help, or anyone else after me, installing the MS build tools fixed this for me.

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools --vs2017
```

remember to run this with PowerShell with administrator permissions (search for PowerShell, right click it and select "run as administrator")

update: also do this:
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1747#issuecomment-491692750, but set the last one to `npm config set msvs_version 2017` instead of `npm config set msvs_version 2015`

then run
`npm install node-pre-gyp`
and `npm install @discordjs/opus`