# Error: failed to push some refs in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-cli

I was following a course online on how to deploy in Heroku. I made a Git repository and uploaded and committed all the files there. Then I typed these commands:

1. `heroku create`
2. `heroku git:remote -a name_provided_by_heroku`
3. `git push heroku main`

After command **3** I faced this error in cmd:

```
Enumerating objects: 4357, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4357/4357), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4125/4125), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4357/4357), 3.64 MiB | 297.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4357 (delta 935), reused 3 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 12.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 12.20.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.14.8
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
remote:        Rebuilding any native modules
remote:
remote:        > bcrypt@5.0.0 install /tmp/build_88514da7/node_modules/bcrypt
remote:        > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
remote:
remote:        sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 126
remote:        npm ERR! bcrypt@5.0.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 126
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@5.0.0 install script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.MO7JR/_logs/2020-12-15T17_16_14_007Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:
remote:        - node_modules checked into source control
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#only-git-the-important-bits
remote:
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to safe-dawn-68695.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/safe-dawn-68695.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/safe-dawn-68695.git'
```

I am new to Heroku, so I am not able to get what the error is saying. Also tried using `git push heroku HEAD:master` but faced the same error.

How do I solve this?

Comment: the problem is with your bycript have you googled the error message?

Comment: yes i googled this error and found some answers on making new repo then following same method , trying 'git push heroku HEAD:master' which worked for others and also created a side branch then tried to deploy on it but the same error showed up.There was no mention of bcrypt so i was not able to dig much.

Comment: because it fails here   > bcrypt@5.0.0 install /tmp/build_88514da7/node_modules/bcrypt
remote:        > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
remote:
remote:        sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied

Comment: so what should be my next step for solving this issue?I uninstalled and reinstalled bcrypt but it didnt worked

Comment: do you need this module?

Comment: I would try without it

Comment: i am using this module for crypting the passwords , as for now i am just practicing on building react projects so i wont be needed it that much.You can try without it.Thank you for replying.

Comment: check out my answer. I think this should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refering this article: [node-pre-gyp: Permission denied in heroku push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56530659/node-pre-gyp-permission-denied-in-heroku-push)

> Remove node_modules folder in your root folder rm -rf node_modules beacuse heroku will install all your dependencies, I hope this will work

So remove your node modules folder and do 1 2 3 again

Comment: It worked!!Thanks a lot for your time and effort in resolving this issue.I really appreciate it.