# heroku push with npm problems

Tags: heroku, discord.js

im trying to push my discord app to heroku but there are some problems, can someone help me?
i think this is from my npm or something idk

```
       Resolving node version 14.x...
       Downloading and installing node 14.17.1...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.13
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
       Rebuilding any native modules
       
       > @discordjs/opus@0.5.3 install /tmp/build_b5827880/node_modules/@discordjs/opus
       > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
       
       sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! errno 126
       npm ERR! @discordjs/opus@0.5.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
       npm ERR! Exit status 126
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Failed at the @discordjs/opus@0.5.3 install script.
       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.7tseI/_logs/2021-06-16T14_44_27_673Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
```

Comment: Do you push your `node_modules` folder too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the `node_modules` folder and let heroku install them, **make sure you have `package.json`**

also check [node-pre-gyp: Permission denied in heroku push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56530659/node-pre-gyp-permission-denied-in-heroku-push)