# Failed to deploy expressjs to heroku

Tags: node.js, express, github, heroku

so im trying to deploy my expressjs server , i've already done the login between heroku and github but after i execute the command `git push heroku master` i get this type of error

```js
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 14.x...
       Downloading and installing node 14.17.3...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.13
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
       Rebuilding any native modules
       
       > bcrypt@5.0.1 install /tmp/build_e68eccdb/node_modules/bcrypt
       > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
       
       sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! errno 126
       npm ERR! bcrypt@5.0.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
       npm ERR! Exit status 126
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@5.0.1 install script.
       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.F7UGs/_logs/2021-07-17T18_32_02_636Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - node_modules checked into source control
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#only-git-the-important-bits
       
       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

this is package.json

```js
{
  "name": "Server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "Server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.4",
    "nexmo": "^2.9.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.0",
    "textbelt": "0.0.4",
    "twilio": "^3.61.0"
  }
}
```

i tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstall them again but it doesnt work
is there any solution for this ?
Thanks !

Comment: what is your local nodejs version?

Comment: my nodejs version is v14.15.4 , i've update my post !

Comment: Just delete the node modules because herkou build them for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56530659/node-pre-gyp-permission-denied-in-heroku-push

Comment: I did that but still the same problem , i tried deleting node_modules manually and then i did npm install but it's not working