# I keep having a Herkou Error that Acces is Denied

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

im having this error with launching heroku and i dont know what to do because ive never used heroku before, im trying to get my discord.js to be hosted 24/7 so i dont have to do it all the time and have my computer running the error says that it is because i dont have permissions but i dont know how to enable them

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack

-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs

-----> Node.js app detected

       

-----> Creating runtime environment

       

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error

       NODE_VERBOSE=false

       NODE_ENV=production

       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true

       

-----> Installing binaries

       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified

       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       

       Resolving node version 14.x...

       Downloading and installing node 14.17.5...

       Using default npm version: 6.14.14

       

-----> Installing dependencies

       Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)

       Rebuilding any native modules

       

       > @discordjs/opus@0.5.3 install /tmp/build_fbbcbd63/node_modules/@discordjs/opus

       > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

       

       sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied

       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

       npm ERR! errno 126

       npm ERR! @discordjs/opus@0.5.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`

       npm ERR! Exit status 126

       npm ERR! 

       npm ERR! Failed at the @discordjs/opus@0.5.3 install script.

       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

       

       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.w8Q2V/_logs/2021-08-30T11_52_05_908Z-debug.log

-----> Build failed

       

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:

       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       

       Some possible problems:

       

       - node_modules checked into source control

         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#only-git-the-important-bits

       

       - Node version not specified in package.json

         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version

       

       Love,

       Heroku

       

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.

 !     Push failed
```

Comment: It looks like an issue caused when installing the `@discordjs/opus` package. Try out the [debugging steps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys#install-and-build-script-failures) to see if you can fix the issue, or try using something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node-pre-gyp: Permission denied in heroku push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56530659/node-pre-gyp-permission-denied-in-heroku-push)