# I need to push my app to heroku via git, but i get error "Push failed

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I have my app created with node.js, I need to push it to my repository in heroku, but is get an error of push failed, i have included error information appear from my console. Please anyone who can help me

```
$ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 3928, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3928/3928), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads  
Compressing objects: 100% (3774/3774), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3928/3928), 4.54 MiB | 153.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3928 (delta 735), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  10.15.3
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 10.15.3...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 10.15.3...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.4.1
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
remote:        Rebuilding any native modules
remote:        
remote:        > bcrypt@3.0.6 install /tmp/build_c2d2c217441a5d9a6c6d5e4798bcaba5/node_modules/bcrypt
remote:        > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
remote:
remote:        sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 126
remote:        npm ERR! bcrypt@3.0.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 126
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.6 install script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.zomUn/_logs/2019-11-03T17_00_27_739Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

Comment: Did you see this from the remote side? "sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied"

Comment: Maybe look at the full log.

Comment: @daniel how do i solve this error

Comment: @Luca the full log is that one i posted and i have stacked there and i need someone who can help me

Comment: As a naive wild guess, you're trying to install `bcrypt` from npm and don't have permissions to do so on heroku.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287669/nodejs-bcrypt-heroku-fail-deploy sounds similar but not an exact dup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [failed to push my existing project to heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58678667/failed-to-push-my-existing-project-to-heroku)

Comment: @phd i have installed bcryptjs and add the engines of the node version  package.json but the error is still persisting

Answer (score 1):

the error was due to node_modules so what i did was to run this code to my project terminal

```
$echo "node_modules" >> .gitignore
$git rm -r --cached node_modules
$git commit -am 'untracked node_modules'
```

and i managed to deploy my app to heroku

Answer (score 0):

```
git rm -r --cached node_modules
git commit -m'Remove node_modules'
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.