# Heroku shows Application Error for NodeJS app even though it runs perfectly in my local machine

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

after I deploy my project into Heroku and run the project. But it shows following error in my browser.

Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command

this is error shown in the application log

2022-05-25T16:04:26.597488+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2022-05-25T16:04:28.499361+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server`

2022-05-25T16:04:30.162332+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1189

2022-05-25T16:04:30.162345+00:00 app[web.1]:   return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));

2022-05-25T16:04:30.162345+00:00 app[web.1]:                  ^
2022-05-25T16:04:30.162346+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-25T16:04:30.162346+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: /app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header

2022-05-25T16:04:30.162346+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1189:18)

2022-05-25T16:04:30.162347+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)

2022-05-25T16:04:30.162347+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)

2022-05-25T16:04:30.162347+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)

2022-05-25T16:04:30.162347+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)

2022-05-25T16:04:30.162348+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object. (/app/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)

2022-05-25T16:04:30.162348+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)

2022-05-25T16:04:30.162348+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)

2022-05-25T16:04:30.162349+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)

2022-05-25T16:04:30.162349+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) {

2022-05-25T16:04:30.162349+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'

2022-05-25T16:04:30.162349+00:00 app[web.1]: }

here is my code

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const cors = require('cors')
const connectDB = require('./config/db')
const passport = require ('passport')
const bodyparser = require('body-parser')
const routes = require('./routes/index')

connectDB()

const app = express()

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'){
    app.use(morgan('dev'))
}

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(bodyparser.json())
app.use(routes)
app.use(passport.initialize())
require('./config/passport')(passport)

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`))
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const actions = require('../methods/actions')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.send('Hello World')
})

router.get('/dashboard', (req,res)=>{
    res.send('dashboard')
})

//@desc Adding New User
//@route POST/adduser
router.post('/adduser', actions.addNew)

//@desc Authenticate User
//@route POST/authenticate
router.post('/authenticate', actions.authenticate)

//@desc get info on a User
//@route POST/getinfo
router.get('/getinfo', actions.getinfo)
module.exports = router
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ceyloncrafts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "ceylon crafts ",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "connect-mongo": "^4.6.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.6",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.4",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "passport": "^0.5.3",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

db.js

```
const mongoose =  require('mongoose')
const dbConfig = require ('./dbconfig')

//connect database
const connectDB = async()=>{
    try{
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(dbConfig.database,{
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        })
        console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`)
    }
    catch(err){
        console.error(err)
        process.exit(1)
    }
}

module.exports = connectDB
```

action.js

```
var Handicraftmen = require('../models/handicraftmen')
var jwt = require('jwt-simple')
var config = require('../config/dbconfig')

var functions = {
    addNew: function(req,res){
        if((!req.body.firstName) || (!req.body.lastName) || (!req.body.email) || (!req.body.password) || (!req.body.NIC) || (!req.body.telephoneNo) || (!req.body.shopName) || (!req.body.shopAddress) || (!req.body.accountNo) || (!req.body.benificiaryName) || (!req.body.bank) || (!req.body.branch)){
            res.json({success: false, msg:'Enter all fields'})
        }
        else{
            var newHandicraftmen = Handicraftmen({
                firstName: req.body.firstName,
                lastName: req.body.lastName,
                email: req.body.email,
                password: req.body.password,
                NIC: req.body.NIC,
                telephoneNo: req.body.telephoneNo,
                shopName: req.body.shopName,
                shopAddress: req.body.shopAddress,
                accountNo: req.body.accountNo,
                benificiaryName: req.body.benificiaryName,
                bank: req.body.bank,
                branch: req.body.branch
            });
            newHandicraftmen.save(function(err, newHandicraftmen){
                if(err){
                    res.json({success: false, msg:'Failed to save'})
                }else{
                    res.json({success: true, msg:'Successfully saved'})
                }
            })
        }
    },
    authenticate: function(req,res){
        Handicraftmen.findOne({
            telephoneNo: req.body.telephoneNo
        }, function (err, handicraftmen){
            if(err) throw err
            if(!handicraftmen){
                res.status(403).send({success: false, msg:'Authentication failed. User not found'})
            }
            else{
                handicraftmen.comparePassword(req.body.password, function(err, isMatch){
                    if(isMatch && !err){
                        var token = jwt.encode(handicraftmen, config.secret)
                        res.json({success:true, token: token})
                    }
                    else{
                        return res.status(403).send({success: false, msg:'Authenticatation failed, wrong password'})
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        )
    },
    getinfo: function(req, res){
        if(req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] ==='Bearer' ){
            var token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
            var decodedtoken = jwt.decode(token, config.secret)
            return res.json({success: true, msg:'Hello ' + decodedtoken.firstName})
        }
        else{
            return res.json({success: false, msg:'No headers'})
        }
    }
}

module.exports = functions
```

passport.js

```
var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy
var ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt

var Handicraftmen = require('../models/handicraftmen')
var config = require('./dbconfig')

module.exports = function(passport){
    var opts = {}

    opts.secretOrKey = config.secret
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt')

    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done){
        Handicraftmen.find({
            id: jwt_payload.id
        }, function(err, handicraftmen){
            if(err){
                return done(err, false)
            }
            if(handicraftmen){
                return done(null, handicraftmen)
            }
            else{
                return done(null, false)
            }
        }
        )
    }))
}
```

Comment: The error asked you to check your logs. So.. I also want to see those logs to know what the error is

Comment: @sciunichalaka, please [edit] your question and add _all_ the errors from the log. The `favicon.ico` is irrelevant.

Comment: I have updated the question with the application log.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my error.

bcrypt is not working on the heroku. bcryptjs is the version worked in heroku.

[Nodejs Bcrypt + Heroku fail deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287669/nodejs-bcrypt-heroku-fail-deploy)